# bash : replace variable value inside ' '

Tags: shell, variables

Sorry if the question is very straight forward but am a newbie to shell scripting. 
I am trying to write something like this :

```
for i in {1..20}
do
   curl "something $i ........ -d  'something "$i" something' "
done
```

The problem is that the second `$i` inside the single quotes part '' is not being replaced. What should be done to get it working ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As said above, parameters are not expanded inside single quotes, you have to use double quotes. The only point is that since it occurs in a already double-quoted string, you have to escape them with a backslash (`\`), like this:

```
$ foo=bar
$ eval "echo \"something \\\"$foo\\\"\""
something "bar"
```

Note that there are three `\` before the innermost `"`, as this will be expanded twice (once when evaluating the argument of `eval` and once when evaluating the argument of `echo`)

Answer (score 2):

This is because variables inside the single quotes `''` are not being replaced. If you want variable substitution, you need to get rid of the single quotes.

You coul maybe pre-initialize that variable

```
foo="something $i bla bla bla"
curl "something ... ${foo}something"
```

Comment: Even though the whole statement is a string enclosed in "" ?

Comment: Yes, the variable substitution works within double quotes `""`. I see no problem with this. Only variables within single quotes will not be replaced as I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Your quoting is not correct. You don't need double quotes around the second `$i` because the whole thing is already surrounded in double-quotes.

Change it to the following:

```
for i in {1..20}
do
   curl "something $i ........ -d  'something $i something'"
done
```